# obtaining the critical values needed for the kolmogorov-smirnov test

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, kolmogorov-smirnov

I'm talking about retrieving the values of this table media a python formula

https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/GG/FACULTY/ITO/GG413/K_S_Table_one_Sample.pdf

i've been looking for a while but scipy functions do not look for this value and tbh I'm getting pretty confused over here.

I've been looking inside scipy built in formulas, without success. For example, in the aforementioned table, D[0.1, 10] == 0.36866. Yet scipy.stats.kstest does NOT return this same value, no matter how much do I play with my data.

Comment: The problem you have is that `scipy.stats.kstest` is implementing the test itself, while your table of critical values is used to interpret the test. There is a paper here: https://luk.staff.ugm.ac.id/stat/ks/IJAS_3-4_2009_07_Facchinetti.pdf with Matlab code in the Appendix - I will try and port this tomorrow if nobody else responds in the meantime.

Comment: other tables have their equivalent in python (scipi, specifically). for example, the values of square chi (or inverse chi if you're using excel) can be found inside chi2.ppf. I can't say the same for Kolmogorov-smirnov. That paper you posted is WAY over my head, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with `scipy`, using the `ksone` distribution and its `ppf` ([percent point function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.ppf)) method, rather than the `kstest`:

```
from scipy.stats import ksone

def ks_critical_value(n_trials, alpha):
    return ksone.ppf(1-alpha/2, n_trials)
```

Printing a table of critical values:

```
from __future__ import print_function # For Python 2

trials = range(1, 41)
alphas = [0.1, 0.05, 0.02, 0.01]

# Print table headers
print('{:<6}|{:<6} Level of significance, alpha'.format(' ', ' '))
print('{:<6}|{:>8} {:>8} {:>8} {:>8}'.format(*['Trials'] + alphas))
print('-' * 42)
# Print critical values for each n_trials x alpha combination
for t in trials:
    print('{:6d}|{:>8.5f} {:>8.5f} {:>8.5f} {:>8.5f}'
          .format(*[t] + [ks_critical_value(t, a) for a in alphas]))
    if t % 10 == 0:
        print()
```

Partial output:

```
      |       Level of significance, alpha
Trials|     0.1     0.05     0.02     0.01
------------------------------------------
     1|     nan      nan      nan      nan
     2| 0.77639  0.84189      nan      nan
     3| 0.63604  0.70760  0.78456  0.82900
     4| 0.56522  0.62394  0.68887  0.73424
     5| 0.50945  0.56328  0.62718  0.66853
     6| 0.46799  0.51926  0.57741  0.61661
     7| 0.43607  0.48342  0.53844  0.57581
     8| 0.40962  0.45427  0.50654  0.54179
     9| 0.38746  0.43001  0.47960  0.51332
    10| 0.36866  0.40925  0.45662  0.48893

    11| 0.35242  0.39122  0.43670  0.46770
    12| 0.33815  0.37543  0.41918  0.44905
    13| 0.32549  0.36143  0.40362  0.43247
    14| 0.31417  0.34890  0.38970  0.41762
    15| 0.30397  0.33760  0.37713  0.40420
    16| 0.29472  0.32733  0.36571  0.39201
    17| 0.28627  0.31796  0.35528  0.38086
    18| 0.27851  0.30936  0.34569  0.37062
    19| 0.27136  0.30143  0.33685  0.36117
    20| 0.26473  0.29408  0.32866  0.35241
```

We need some additional feedback from a statistician on (a) why we get `np.nan` values for the top two rows (I assume because the critical values for these combinations of `n_trials` and `alpha` are purely theoretical, and not achievable in practice), and (b) why the `ksone.ppf` method needs `alpha` to be divided by 2? I will edit this answer to include that information.

You can see though, that besides the initial missing values, this table generates identical results to [the table in your question](https://www.soest.hawaii.edu/GG/FACULTY/ITO/GG413/K_S_Table_one_Sample.pdf), and to the table on page 16 of [this paper](https://luk.staff.ugm.ac.id/stat/ks/IJAS_3-4_2009_07_Facchinetti.pdf).